# Java Web Service Client to WCF Web Service Server. Interoperability Solution

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap, wcf-interoperability

Has anyone found a way for a WCF Service to be queried by a Java Client? What .NET library did you use and what Java library did you use. Please be specific with specific platforms and library versions. Also, I've found that if the libraries don't use compatible SOAP version specifications that the libraries aren't compatible either. If you know which SOAP version specification, please provide that as well.
-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Java Metro Library version 2.1, http://metro.java.net/2.1/.
Follow the instructions at http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/test-drive-shiny-new-wcf-interop.html.

Answer (score 2):

What problems you for-see if you go ahead with calling your WCF service with Java Client?

The whole point to use standard SOAP based webservices is to have benefits of Interoperability.

WCF (by Microsoft) is standard technology and I understand it implements and follows the standards of WS-I consortium by using the standard SOAP and WSDL specs to support interoperability.

And same is applicable for JAVA and is defined in its JAX-WS specs. Standard tools like axis/cxf/xjc etc is there to help you at java side to use WSDL to generate proxies and call a SOAP based service (developed in any language as long as it follows the SOAP bindings, WSDL specifications etc.)

Comment: You can run into issues from time to time, but we have several WCF services consumed by JAVA, PHP, and even uniface.

Comment: @Sakura, many times the bindings aren't compatible. That is why I'm asking for specific library versions.

Comment: @jparram are you using the old asmx web services or the new svc WCF services. If you are using the svc services, please share more about your solution, as I asked above.

Comment: +1 for CXF. Use it all the time for knarly WS-Addressing and WS-Security requirements .. even client signing and NTLM auth.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with WCF svc and BasicHttpBinding.  BasicHttpBinding should give you the most interop success and uses SOAP 1.1.  We have used .NET 3 and up with Java, PHP and uniface clients.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a Soap 1.2 binding. So, some form of a WSHttpBinding.