# Java Client(Metro) Connecting to WCF Created with ExpressInterop Bindings

Tags: c#, java, wcf, netbeans, wcf-interoperability

I have a WCF Service created with the help of ExpressInteropBindings Extension for VS2010.

**Things Mentioned while creating ExpressInteropBindings:**
**Interoperability Platform** : Metro
**Main Settings**

1)Security : Username over certificate
2)Secure Conversation : NO
3)Reliable Messaging : NO

**Advanced Settings:**

1)Algorithm : Default
2)Encoding : Default

**Certificate Selection:**

1) Store Location : Localmachine
2) Store Name: Root
3) Certificate: I Created one with the CodeProject.com link

Then I created the Simple Java Project using NetBeans

added a webservice client with wsdl location

created my own truststore and added the above created certificate,

Given the username and password as it is Custom Authentication by

"Edit Web Service Attributes" in Netbeans

when i try to call the Service it throws

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.handleGetObject(PropertyResourceBundle.java:166)
>   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)  at
> java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)   at
> java.util.logging.Formatter.formatMessage(Formatter.java:118)     at
> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:151)    at
> java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:211)   at
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:116)     at
> java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:731)     at
> java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:754)   at
> java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:864)     at
> com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policy.CertificateRetriever.digestBST(CertificateRetriever.java:136)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:211)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)    at
> com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)  at
> com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)     at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)     at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)     at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)   at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.getData(Unknown Source)    at
> metrointeropwithoutrandsec.MetroInterOpWithoutRandSec.main(MetroInterOpWithoutRandSec.java:38)
```

Comment: You need to use the Java Metro 2.1 Library. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332829/java-web-service-client-to-wcf-web-service-server-interoperability-solution/22722503#22722503

Comment: @JoshGinn : Thanks for your Reply, without Express Interop Bindings itself , i'm able to access the Web Service from Java. I used WsHttpBinding with UserName over Certificate.